# Which url points to which file

Tags: url-rewriting

Actually i have deployed a wordpress running website on my local environment. I want to have some general instruction that how can i know which file points to which url. Like if i entered the url mysite.com/household-insrtuments. it opens a page in the backend i searched from the text through the project i found that this opens the file name 'housing-facilities.php' so is there any way i can view this ?

Comment: That kind of URLs are rewrited to index.php at server-level; all other needed files are included form there. Your question is a bit confusing. Can you try to elaborate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress has a template hierarchy, he search down the files in your theme until he finds a suitable template for the content hes outputing following the hierarchy.

Here it's a example from de Codex:

If your blog is at `http://example.com/blog/` and a visitor clicks on a link to a category page such as `http://example.com/blog/category/your-cat/`, WordPress looks for a template file in the current theme’s directory that matches the category’s ID to generate the correct page. More specifically, WordPress follows this procedure:

1. Looks for a template file in the current theme’s directory that
   matches the category’s slug. If the category slug is “unicorns,”
   then    WordPress looks for a template file named
   category-unicorns.php.
2. If category-unicorns.php is missing and the category’s ID is 4,
   WordPress looks for a template file named category-4.php.
3. If category-4.php is missing, WordPress will look for a generic
   category template file, category.php.
4. If category.php does not exist, WordPress will look for a generic
   archive template, archive.php.
5. If archive.php is also missing, WordPress will fall back to the main
   theme template file, index.php.

Here's a image that shows the complete hirarchy:

[image: Wordpress template hierarchy]

He will follow this behaviour unless you rewrite it with the [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).

In your case `house-facilities.php` is a [Custom Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use), and `household-instruments` is a page that uses this custom template, go to your Admin -> Pages -> Household Facilities and edit it, on the edit page you will see in the right corner a block called `Page Attributes`, inside that block has a select called `Template` and you will see that `House Facilities Index` is selected.

So what happens? As described in the link above, if you want to create a template for multiple pages to use, you can create a file and register it as an template. To register a file as a template simply put a comment in the top of the file with the line, `Template Name: My Template`, now in the edit page, you can select that file to output any page as you want.

When I'm developing a theme I like to use the [Show Current Template](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/) plugin to see which files the page is loading.

Too learn about the template hierarchy see the [Theme handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Comment: i have not seen any kind of files there which you have mentioned. When i click on the href link it opens the mysite.com/household-insrtuments. just this not any kind of id or unicorn. when i search and changed the text on the housing-facilities.php file it changed the text on the url so it means it was pointing out the housing-facilities.php file.  but i am not getting it how to know each url

Comment: That is just an example of how the template system works in wordpress, I can't say the exacly files of your theme because I don't know him and don't know if you're using, `taxonomies` or `custom post types`, if he has template for them etc. I showed you an example e posted de link for the Codex so you can learn how it works a figure out. And you can also use the plugin, just install it and when you visit a page, will list all the files loaded for that page in the admin bar.

Comment: for the plugin suggestion Thank you for that it is really helping. but still i did not find my question's answer. I thought that there would be a particular pattern in the wordpress to followed for the files.

Comment: And it does, it's the pattern that I explained to you above, he sees if the content it's an Post Type, Taxonomy, Page etc.. and search for a template to output it following the hiararchy in the image. So  `household-instruments` could be a `Custom Post Type` and `house-facilities.php` be a template for this post type or it could be a `term` or a `taxonomy`, It's hard to know when I can't see your files and don't know what `household-instruments` is. That's why I explained how the template system in wordpress work, so you can study it and figure out.

Comment: actually if this url is calling house-facilities. there should be a link to it. I have searched both that from where it is linking these two but i have only found the string coccurences not as a particular link. So i can assume that these could be in database?

Comment: If it's a `post` or a `cutsom post type`, the [permalink](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) is stored in the database, but the template system works with the id or slug of what are you trying to load, just as described in the image.

Comment: okay in my case this is slug. but still i am not finding the link how it is finding the house-ficilities.php file for the household-instuments.

Comment: household-instruments is a post? it's a default `post` or a `custom post type`? house-facilities.php has a comment in the top of the file that contains `Template Name`?

Comment: yeah it has a template name 'House Facilities Index'

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. You have described me with patience bear my questions. I understand now that how this was pointing to this. There is index assigned to it and to the any other page. Thank you +1. i did not have enough repo on this to upvote you. Cheers!